# Sabre StructureFareRules format basis not available error

Tags: sabre

I would like to use Sabre web services, unfortunatelly I got a StructureFareRules response with the following error:

```
<Error ErrorCode="005106" ErrorMessage="FORMAT FARE BASIS NOT AVAILABLE"/>
```

Could somebody please tell me, what are the problems with the following request
body:

```
<S:Body>
        <ns2:StructureFareRulesRQ
            xmlns:ns2="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07"
            xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"
            xmlns:ns5="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader"
            xmlns:ns6="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            xmlns:ns7="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ns2:PriceRequestInformation CurrencyCode="USD">
                <ns2:PassengerTypes>
                    <ns2:PassengerType Code="ADT" Count="1"/>
                </ns2:PassengerTypes>
                <ns2:ReturnAllData Value="1"/>
                <ns2:FreeBaggageSubscriber Ind="true"/>
            </ns2:PriceRequestInformation>
            <ns2:AirItinerary>
                <ns2:OriginDestinationOptions>
                    <ns2:OriginDestinationOption>
                        <ns2:FlightSegment ArrivalDate="2020-08-14T15:55:00" BookingDate="2020-06-11T16:06:10" DepartureDate="2020-08-14T14:30:00" FlightNumber="2467" RealReservationStatus="QF" ResBookDesigCode="L" SegmentNumber="1" SegmentType="A">
                            <ns2:DepartureAirport LocationCode="LAX"/>
                            <ns2:ArrivalAirport LocationCode="SFO"/>
                            <ns2:MarketingAirline Code="AS"/>
                            <ns2:OperatingAirline Code="AS"/>
                        </ns2:FlightSegment>
                        <ns2:SegmentInformation SegmentNumber="1"/>
                        <ns2:PaxTypeInformation FareBasisCode="LH9OAVMN" FareComponentAmount="119.10" FareComponentNumber="1" PassengerType="ADT"/>
                    </ns2:OriginDestinationOption>
                </ns2:OriginDestinationOptions>
            </ns2:AirItinerary>
        </ns2:StructureFareRulesRQ>
    </S:Body>
```

The data in the request are from the Sabre Bargain Finder Max service.

Answer (score 1):

The request structure looks fine as such. Doesn’t seem to have any issues. In any case, you can refer to the following link as well:-

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/utility/get_structured_fare_rules

This is mostly related to the way the service is built. Fare components do not necessarily reflect segments, and check the directionality of the fare. Since you are using BFM, the service will return fare directionality and the actual cities you have to use. Sometimes fares are loaded as full in ATPCO, not only by segments, so that means that the city pair you will have to use in your request will be what you can see in FareComponentBeginAirport and FareComponentEndAirport in BFM's response. Would advise to check with the helpdesk, as you can send them your full payloads and they can check in your PCC as well. Also check that the FaireBasisCode is the same which is returned from BFM result. The error means the code is invalid or no data available for the specified code.